# If in Flutter Expanded is written in Column on iPhone 14 Pro Max, it continues indefinitely. why?

Tags: ios, flutter, user-interface

[image]

How One UI looks on **iPhone 14 Pro Max** and **other phones**.

The code written in **Flutter** is as follows:

```
return SafeArea(
                child: SmartRefresher(
              controller: controller.balanceRefreshController,
              onRefresh: () => controller.onRefreshBalance(),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppPaddings.side),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    // #Balance
                    _getBalanceWidget(controller),

                    // #choose amount
                    Expanded(child: _getChooseAmountWidget(controller)),

                    // #button
                    _getActivatedDefaultButton(controller),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ));
```

With BalanceWidget, the remaining space allocated to the button should have been left to _getChooseAmountWidget.

**But why didn't it happen?**

*(I know how to show button in UI. For example I can use Stack. I wonder why the code doesn't work properly, not show the button)*

**Some cases:**

1. If _getChooseAmountWidget has 4 items:
   [image]
2. If I remove Expanded:

   ```
            // #Balance
            _getBalanceWidget(controller),

            // #choose amount
            // Expanded(child: _getChooseAmountWidget(controller)),

            // #button
            ActivatedDefaultButton(
              isActive: controller.selectedItem != null,...
   ```

[image]

Comment: Try wrapping the column in a `LayoutBuilder` to give it proper constraints

Comment: MindStudio Thanks for the reply, but it didn't help:   LayoutBuilder(
                  builder: (context, boxConstraints) => SizedBox(
                    height: boxConstraints.maxHeight,
                    width: boxConstraints.maxWidth,
                    child: Column(

Comment: This does seem like very strange behaviour. Could it actually be that on the iPhone 14 `_getActivatedDefaultButton` returns a widget of 0 height for some reason?

Comment: Ivo    I will not die like this. The reason is that I tried it on Android phones with the same screen as 14 Pro Max. No such problem. Even if there was a problem, Padding should work. AppPaddings.side = 30.

Comment: Can you try out what happens when you only have like 3 possible amounts in `_getChooseAmountWidget`? So everything fits the screen, to see if the button shows up correctly for iPhone 14 in that case

Comment: Ivo - Yes of course, I added additional cases to the question.